# How to load chrome custom tab when multiple browsers installed in the device and user has set different browser as default instead of chrome browser?

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, chrome-custom-tabs

I am developing one android application in that i need to load all the web URL into chrome custom tab but i am facing one issue when user install multiple browser into their device and they set default browser as different instead of chrome browser in  this case chrome tab is not getting open.

I am following this document and sample.
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Google Chrome package to the customTabsIntent:

```
    CustomTabsIntent tabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build();
    tabsIntent.intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
    tabsIntent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(YOUR_URL));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Above code will not work when user disable/not install chrome browser.

Comment: check the docs, you need to test it's availability, or select anyone available. rather than that, opens normally.
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs#preparing-for%20other%20browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void CustomTab(Activity activity,
                             Uri uri) {
// It returns the chrome package name 
String packageName = CustomTabsHelper.getPackageNameToUse(activity, mUrl);

CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
mCustomTabsIntent = builder
        .setShowTitle(true)
        .build();
builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.colorPrimary));

if ( packageName != null ) {
    mCustomTabsIntent.intent.setPackage(packageName);
}
mCustomTabsIntent.launchUrl(activity, uri);
}
```

If user has installed chrome it will open directly

Comment: What is `CustomTabsHelper`?